# Right join on each row

Tags: t-sql

Is there an easy way to do the following without having to recur to temporary tables or cursors?

“Table 1 right join Table 2, but for each row in Table 1.”

Eg:

```
Table 1, Row 1 right join Table 2.  
Table 1, Row 2 right join Table 2.
```

Etc.
Thanks

**Update 1**

Sorry I should of explained in a bit more detail.

**Table definitions:**
Table1:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]
(  
          [id] [int],  
          [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
          [id_table2] [int] NULL)
```

Table 2.

```
TABLE [dbo].[Table_2]  
(  
[id] [int] NOT NULL,  
[code] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  )
```

**Table 1 data:**

```
Table 1 Data:  
1       Prov1    1  
2       Prov2    2
```

<strike>NULL</strike> 
    <strike>NULL</strike>    <strike>NULL</strike>
**Table 2 data:**

```
Table 2 Data:  
1    01  
2    02  
3    03  
4    04  
5    05
```

<strike>NULL</strike> 
    <strike>NULL</strike>
**If I do the following:**

```
select * from Table_1 as t1  
right join Table_2 as t2 on  
t1.id_table2 =  
t2.id
```

result:

```
1       Prov1    1      1    01  
2       Prov2    2      2    02  
NULL    NULL    NULL    3    03  
NULL    NULL    NULL    4    04  
NULL    NULL    NULL    5    05
```

**Result I'd  like:**

"Right join on each table 1 row"

```
1    Prov1    1       1    01  
1    Prov1    NULL    2    02  
1    Prov1    NULL    3    03  
1    Prov1    NULL    4    04  
1    Prov1    NULL    5    05

2    Prov2    1       1    01  
2    Prov2    NULL    2    02  
2    Prov2    NULL    3    03  
2    Prov2    NULL    4    04  
2    Prov2    NULL    5    05
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data and expected output?

Comment: Rauland, you may want to rephrase your question and add an actual example of the output you would like to get, and possibly some context. It is really not clear (to me at least) what issue you're trying to solve there.

Comment: @Sachin and @Romain Sorry, I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Why have you got `NULL` in your sample data for columns that are declared as not allowing `NULL`?

Comment: @Martin Thanks, I copied directly from Management Studio and included the NULLs by mistake, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be looking for a CROSS JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN.